# Cross tabulation between two sets of columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, crosstab

I have tried to get crosstab of data specified by slice.

But something wrong in syntax.

`data.csv` like the following

```
ia,ib,ic,id,ie,if,ig  
a,0,0,0,e,0,g         
0,b,0,0,e,f,0         
0,0,c,d,0,f,g
```

And then do `python3 test.py` like the following

```
import pandas as pd
import enum

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

class Slices(enum.Enum):
    first = slice(0, 2)
    second = slice(4, 6)

def getCrosstab(*args):
    cols1 = []
    cols1.append(df.iloc[:, args[0].value])
    cols2 = []
    cols2.append(df.iloc[:, args[1].value])
    print( pd.crosstab(cols1, cols2) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getCrosstab(Slices.first, Slices.second)
```

Expected result:

```
col2 ie if ig
col1
ia   1  0  1
ib   1  1  0
ic   0  1  1
```

But I had an error:
**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2), indices imply (2, 3)**

I can not fully understand the meaning of this error.

Please give me your guidance.

Comment: If possible share sample `df`?

Comment: looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) it seems to me that `pd.crosstab` takes `array-like` objects and not full `DataFrame`s

Comment: confused what you trying to do ?

Comment: @meW It was defined as `df = pd.read_csv ('data.csv')` , is not that?

Comment: To make your question clear, have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`melt` twice, once for each set of columns, and then call `crosstab`:

```
u = (df.melt(['ia', 'ib', 'ic'], var_name='C', value_name='D')
       .melt(['C', 'D'], var_name='A', value_name='B')
       .query("B != '0' and D != '0'"))

pd.crosstab(u.A, u.C)

C   id  ie  if  ig
A                 
ia   0   1   0   1
ib   0   1   1   0
ic   1   0   1   1
```

---

```
def crosstab_for(df, sliceA, sliceB):
    u = (df.reindex(df.columns[sliceA] | df.columns[sliceB], axis=1)
           .melt(df.columns[sliceA], var_name='C', value_name='D')
           .melt(['C', 'D'], var_name='A', value_name='B')
           .query("B != '0' and D != '0'"))

    return pd.crosstab(u.A, u.C)

crosstab_for(df, slice(0, 3), slice(4, 7))

C   ie  if  ig
A             
ia   1   0   1
ib   1   1   0
ic   0   1   1
```